# Generic date value return on IF argument

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Snip of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5BJv.png)

Having some issues returning a generic year value with a code that was built before me. If there is a date in column F then it returns just fine. However with a blank value it is giving the generic date. I have tried some LEN and ISBLANK ideas but each time I get error messages or too many arguments. Inside E3 is the following code:

```
=IF($D3="Forklift",DATE(YEAR([@[Annual Validation Date ]])+2,MONTH([@[Annual Validation Date ]]),DAY([@[Annual Validation Date ]])),DATE(YEAR([@[Annual Validation Date ]])+1,MONTH([@[Annual Validation Date ]]),DAY([@[Annual Validation Date ]])))
```

I am sure there is an easy fix but for some reason I can't see it. Any help would be much appreciate!

EDIT: If column F is blank, I would like it to return nothing and have column E be blank.

Comment: What should it return if column F is blank?

Comment: If column F is blank, I would like it to return nothing and have column E be blank.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over-thinking the date column by trying to test it for length or for “isblank.”  Excel stores dates as a numeric value that represents whole and fractional days since 1/0/1900.  So a date is stored simply as a numeric value like 44785.746.  So check if it is > 0, not how long it is.

Also, if you have O365, then you have access to the EDATE() function that does exactly what you want to do much easier.

Instead of dismantling the date and reassembling with an additional year, you equation becomes:

```
=IF($D3=“Forklift”,EDATE([@[Annual Validation Date][,24),EDATE([@[Annual Validation Date]],12))
```

Then it becomes easier to incorporate that into a test of the date field:

```
=IF([@[Annual Validation Date]]>0, trueStuffHere, “”)
```

Which becomes:

```
=IF([@[Annual Validation Date]]>0, IF($D3=“Forklift”,EDATE([@[Annual Validation Date]],24),EDATE([@[Annual Validation Date]],12)), “”)
```

Edit:  You can simplify this with LET:

```
=LET(
avd,[@[Annual Validation Date]],
IF(avd="","",IF($D2="Forklift",EDATE(avd,12),EDATE(avd,24)))
)
```

(I like to use alt-enters to break a LET formula up into lines for readability)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried putting this formula in and sadly I got a #NAME? error. I changed the reference from Annual Validation Date to the column to test afterwards and was still getting the same error. By chance any idea on why this may be happening?

Comment: @CaptainWinks my formulas threw an error because **I** entered them incorrectly.  Your question had the table references in correct form:  [@[Annual Validation Date]] where in my haste I accidentally shortened them to simply @[Annual Validation Date].  If you put them in your form they should work.  If you have access to the LET function you can create a very short simple function while still using the column names instead of cell references.  I'll edit the answer and may also show the LET example.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing some more research and found this worked with no reference errors:

```
=IF($F2="","",IF($D2="Forklift",EDATE($F2,12),EDATE($F2,24)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).